# Limit the database access though PHP

Tags: php, api, plugins, frameworks

For a plugin system I am writing, I need to write a database API. But I want to restrict database access, so plugins can't see other tables than the ones they created through a specific function. How would I enable plugins to use SQL, but not give them full access at the same time?

Here is some code, it may not be working, but it shows the idea behind it:

```
class Api_Database {
    private $pluginid;

    function __construct($pluginid) {
        $this->pluginid = $pluginid;
    } 

    function query($sql, $tablename) {
        $db = new Sys_Database;
        $db->query(str_replace('{table}', $pluginid.$tablename, $sql));
    }
}
```

Am I thinking in the right direction here? How would you create such a system, only more secure?

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to create a table containing the list of created tables linked to the user...

Something like :

```
privileges
user_id
table_name
```

And in your query

```
SELECT FROM privileges WHERE user_id = '{user_id}' and table_name = '{table}';
```

And after check if the row exist. If yes, the user have the right to use the table!

```
class Api_Database {
    private $pluginid;

    function __construct($pluginid) {
        $this->pluginid = $pluginid;
    } 

    function query($sql, $tablename) {
        $hasPrivilege = $this->checkPrivileges($tablename, $userid);

        if(!$hasPrivilege) return false; //for example

        $db = new Sys_Database;
        $db->query(str_replace('{table}', $pluginid.$tablename, $sql));
    }

    function checkPrivileges($table, $user_id) {
        $db = new Sys_Database;
        $result = $db->query('SELECT id FROM privileges WHERE user_id = "'.$user_id.'" AND table_name = "'.$table.'"');
        return ($result && $result->num_rows);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

So if I understand correctly, you are using a PHP plugin to access SQL data, but you can't or doesn't want to change it.
You cant' add SQL users too, and you wan't to restrict PHP Dev to make some queries in some table via PHP?? Hum... Impossible!

Because to be able to disallow database table access, YOU HAVE TO MANIPULATE PHP OR MYSQL USERS...
Or if I'm wrong, sorry, it's difficult to follow you!

Comment: I see, but that's not the problem. The point is dat in string $sql, {table} might not be present, so a plugin skip the whole table-replacing part, therefore it can access system tables and tables belonging to other plugins.

Comment: You can so create a limited mysql account for the conn!

Comment: Yes, I could do that, but I am creating a piece of software that should run on other servers too, which may not be able to create limited MySQL accounts. (Webhosting and such.)

Comment: You can also limit some table access using an array with reserved tables : `array('mysql', 'information_schema')` and add a test before each sql!

Comment: That might work, but that doesn't solve the first issue: how to prevent plugins from submitting a query like this: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=10 OR username={tablename}`. Since probably nobody has a username {tablename}, the user with id=10 was fetched. Or {tablename} is just left out the query at all.

Comment: What `tablename` is on your example? I don't understand why you compare with `username` field? You want to create a table per user, and to block each user to there own table?

Comment: No no. The point is that I don't develop plugins. So plugins could access other tables, not meant for them, like, in this case, the users table. I need that restricted. The comparison with username is just an example to show how I could still use {tablename} and read from the wrong table at the same time.